# Which wording for a button works better at the end of steps in a lightbox: Close or Continue or else?

Tags: copywriting

I have a lightbox popup, and after a series of steps of booking, you receive a confirmation still in the lightbox, I am inserting in the bottom right a link that says "close", but to me it feels too much robot kind, and not so human (even because on top right I have already the icon "close").

I would like to have something more human like "continue", but some people in my team argue back that continue it make them feel "continue to what?" after doing a booking they might not interested in anything else, so what to use as text to attract the people back to the homepage without been too robotic or obvious?

What you think? What it would be a best practice for this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If this is the last step and there's nothing more for the user to do in the lightbox, then clicking this link is the only thing that the user can do on the screen. As such, don't hide it in some corner forcing the user to look for it, feeling "OK, now how do I close this thing?". Bring it to the center of the screen, make it a nice and shiny button, and say something like "Return to MyCoolWebsite", or at the very least "Done".

Comment: There are 2 ways, the top right icon "close button" with the X, and the bottom down right link that is a text. Which "Return to..." I like it, and Done as well. I am waiting for more proposal

Comment: Anyway I gave you a +1 :) (I forgot to say it)

Answer (score 3):

"Finish" might work, clicking it closes lightbox and take user back to website.

"Done" is also fine.

Definitely NOT "Continue"  that does mean something comes next and would be confusing for most users.

Answer (score 0):

#### [OK](http://folklore.org/StoryView.py?&story=Do_It.txt)